# Error x = atomic and x = non numeric while computing linear model and histograms what does that mean?

Tags: r, histogram, boxplot, numeric, lm

I get the error that my vector is non numeric while it is:

```
fitmodel <-lm(formula=adg_tot ~ behandeling*week + blok, data=data_adfi_adg_fcr_weekinone)
tab_model(fitmodel)
summary(fitmodel)
anova(fitmodel)
resids_lmer <- residuals(fitmodel)
hist(fitmodel)
boxplot(fitmodel)
shapiro.test(fitmodel)
```

the errors I receive are:

```
resids_lmer <- residuals(fitmodel)
> hist(fitmodel)
Error in hist.default(fitmodel) : 'x' must be numeric
> boxplot(fitmodel)
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
> shapiro.test(fitmodel) #p-value > 0.05 normal distribution
Error in shapiro.test(fitmodel) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
> 
aswell as 'adg_tot' and 'behandeling' are numeric
```

I tried to change the vectors in numeric, character of factor but it did not help.

Comment: Do you mean to be plotting your resids_lmer ? You are plotting the model, not a vector